# Advantage of "forcing" the partition

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a topic `theimportanttopic` with three partitions.

Is an advantage to "forcing" the partition assignment?

For instance, I have three consumers in one group. I want consumer1 to always and only consume from partition-0, consumer2 to always and only consume from partition-1 and consumer3 to always and only consume from partition-2.

One consumer should not touch any other partition at any point of time except the one that was assigned.

A drawback I can think of is that when one of the consumers goes down, no one is consuming from the partition.

Let's suppose a fancy self-healing architecture is in place, can bring back any of those lost consumer back very efficiently.

Would it be an advantage, knowing there won't be any partition reassignment cost to the healthy consumers? The healthy consumers can focus on their own partition, etc.

Are there any other pros and cons?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#tip-assign-all-parts
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#manual-assignment

It seems the API allow possibility of forcing the partition, I was wondering if this use case was one of the purposes of this design.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know what is the "number" of each consumer? Based on your last questions, you've either used kubernetes, or setting concurrency in Spring Kafka. In either case, pods/threads rebalance across partitions of the *same* executable application... Therefore, you cannot scale them *and assign* to specific partitions without extra external locking logic.

In my opinion, all executable consumers should be equally be able to handle any partition.

Plus, as you pointed out, there's downtime if one stops.

But, the use case is to exactly match the producer. You've produced data by some custom partitioner logic, therefore, you need exact consumers to read only a subset of that data.

Also, assignment doesn't use consumer groups, so while there would be no rebalancing, it makes it not possible to monitor lag using tools like Burrow or consumer groups cli. Lag would need gathered directly from the consumer metrics themselves.

Comment: How do you know what is the "number" of each consumer?  -> through some kubernetes StatefulSet and custom logic, but please give me the benefice of the doubt I am able to know the "number" easily

Comment: Plus, as you pointed out, there's downtime if one stops. -> we do have a way to recreate the kubernetes pod (the consumer) very fast. Please give me the benefice of the doubt the downtime is very little

Comment: @PatPanda The "con" is that it is an anti-pattern. Why do you want to do it at all? You will need some "custom logic" to say `if (record.partition == getPodNumber())`, etc. You said containers start fast, and previously said, they never stop at all, so why do you care about rebalancing that is avoided when using `assign` API? (which is the main "pro", other than explicitly subscribing to certain event types, which realistically should be in their own topic, anyway, and consumed using `subscribe` API)